# Trigonometric equation with sine graph

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, problem-solving

If sin^-1(1/2)=30 degrees
,[solve the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaVDF.png)
I've never seen anything like this and I can't find anything in my textbook so an explanation would be appreciated

Comment: we get $$x=\frac{7\pi}{6}$$ or $$x=\frac{11\pi}{6}$$

Comment: Here you have a trigonometric equation, not an inequality.

Comment: How does the [tag:random-graphs] tag keep seeming relevant to questions about graphs of functions, even *after* the description has been edited to clarify that you shouldn't do this? There's not even any randomness in this problem.

Comment: The graph just looked pretty random to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know identity $\sin (-x)=-\sin x$, and can solve $\sin x=\frac{1}{2}$ then $-x$ will be the solution of your original equation. Please be aware that you'll have two solutions.

If you are given a graph of $y=\sin x$ then you can draw line $y=-\frac{1}{2}$ and  your solutions will be points of intersection of the sine graph and that line.

Comment: Hi yeah that looks right on the graph but the graph is only a sketch is there a more algebraic way of solving this as in the answer book it says x=180+30=210 or x=360-30 ,do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: You know that $\sin 30°=0.5$, thus $\sin (-30°)=-0.5$ so one solution is -30° or 360°-30°=330°. Similarly,   $\sin (180°-30°)=0.5$ so the other solution is  360°-150°=210°

Answer (score 0):

In general : If $\sin x=\sin\alpha,$ then $x=n\pi+(-1)^{n}\alpha$ for any $n\in\Bbb{Z}.$

For your problem, we have $\sin x=\sin (-30^0)$ and choose values of $n$ so that $x$ is in the given range.